# ASP.NET Web API with OpenID Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, openid, dotnetopenauth

I'm looking for a way how to integrate OpenID Authentication into my API (ASP.NET Web API). I didn't find an example so far. I already had a look at http://dotnetopenauth.net/ and http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on but because it's just an API I don't want to redirect to a webpage but rather to an OpenID Provider API...

Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Authentication protocols like OpenID and OAuth were designed for user interaction so that the user can approve access to the 3rd party API. There isn't really a way to use them solely with Web API.